# Database structure for location based requests

Tags: database, firebase, database-design

I am developing an application where the user can request data based on its current location. So for example I have a big pool of local stores all over the world and when the user hits a query just the stores nearby his location gets queried to match. Same as in tinder, there are a lot of people in the database but one user can only see people around his location. How must the database be structured, cause I guess just querying the whole database pool, possible out of million entries, to find people that match with your geo location is bad practice? What is the architecture similar applications use? Thanks for tips.

Answer (score -1):

I would say querying the whole database pool and letting the database take care of optimization is actually good practice. However, you need to be careful in defining your table so that these queries will be efficient.

In particular, you'll want a spatial two-dimensional index on the column. PostGIS is great for this: http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Then, when you query, use [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

If you are interested in learning about how this actually looks like when laid out on memory/disk, start with r-tree indexes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree